# Code Coverage for JSON.Deserialize object in apex test classes in salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, callout

I am writing test classes for apex classes code coverage.
In one apex class, I am sending request to a website and getting response in json format. Then I am deserializing the response string into inner-class objects. That portion is not being covered by me.

**My Apex class code is:**

```
public class SearchCompanyApex {
    public SearchResultJSON sJsonR{get;set;}
    public string myAPIKey {get; set;}
    public List<IncomeStatement> listIncomeStateValues{get;set;}

    public string result_of_httpReq {get; set;}


    public void loadPage(){
        string symbol = queryString('c');

        if(symbol !=null || symbol !='' ){                                                     
            generalInfo(symbol);    
        }
    }

    // Method that is requesting the data from website and assigning the data to variables of this class..
    private void generalInfo(string symbol){

        result_of_httpReq =  httpReq(symbol);
        sJsonR = (SearchResultJSON)JSON.deserialize(result_of_httpReq, SearchResultJSON.class);

    //=================== Not Covered code Start ================== Main is sJsonR.items[0].attributes not covered...  

        // Adding values in list to use it to save data in salesforce..  
        listIncomeStateValues = new List<IncomeStatement>{
            new IncomeStatement('Description', sJsonR.items[0].description,'Description__c'),
            new IncomeStatement('Company Title', sJsonR.items[0].title,'Name')
        };

    //=================== Not Covered code End  ===================

    }


    // Class to make a json obect containing the inoformation of all the fields of this class..
    public Class SearchResultJSON{
        public List<SearchedDocs> items;
    }

    public Class SearchedDocs{
        public string description{get;set;}
        public string title {get;set;}
        public list<list<string>> data{get;set;}
    }


    // Wrapper Class for CompaniesHouse Data 
    Public Class IncomeStatement{
        Public String Field{get;set;}
        Public String Value{get;set;}
        Public String SFField{get;set;}
        Public String SFValue{get;set;}


       // Constructor. Initializing values...
        public IncomeStatement(string Field, string Value,string SFField){
            this.Field = Field;
            this.Value = Value;
            this.SFValue = Value;
            this.SFField = SFField;
        }
    }
}
```

**And Test Class code is:**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class SearchCompanyApex_TestClass {

     static testMethod void myTest() {

        // Making object of class to be covered...
        SearchCompanyApex class_test = new SearchCompanyApex();

        // Making object of inner class of target class to be covered...
        SearchCompanyApex.SearchedDocs jsonobject_test = new SearchCompanyApex.SearchedDocs();
        jsonobject_test.description = 'Company description';
        jsonobject_test.title = 'Company Name';

        // Making list for different objects to map into fields...
        List<SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement> listJSONDocs = new List<SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement>();

        SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement list_description = new SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement('Description', jsonobject_test.description, 'Description__c');
        SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement list_company_title = new SearchCompanyApex.IncomeStatement('Company Title', jsonobject_test.title, 'Name');

        listJSONDocs.add(list_description);
        listJSONDocs.add(list_company_title);

        class_test.listIncomeStateValues = listJSONDocs;
        // Checking whether Website API key is equal to the saved key...    
        System.assertEquals(class_test.listIncomeStateValues, listJSONDocs);


        // It is the main part of this test class. It is call to "getAPIKeyMock" to avoid error : "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts." 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new GetAPIKeyMock(class_test.result_of_httpReq));

        // Calling the method "loadPage()" ...
        class_test.loadPage(); 


        SearchCompanyApex.SearchResultJSON jsonList_test = new SearchCompanyApex.SearchResultJSON();
        jsonList_test.items.add(jsonobject_test);

        class_test.sJsonR.items[0].title = jsonList_test.items[0].title;
        class_test.sJsonR.items[0].description = jsonList_test.items[0].description;


        // Checking whether Website API key is equal to the saved key...    
        System.assertEquals(class_test.sJsonR.items[0].title, 'Company Name');

        // Checking whether Website API key is equal to the saved key...    
        System.assertEquals(class_test.sJsonR.items[0].description, 'Company description');

    }


    // This is an inner class to handle WebService callout problems.
    private class GetAPIKeyMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        private string returned_SJSONResult;

        public GetAPIKeyMock(string returned_SJSONResult) {
            this.returned_SJSONResult = returned_SJSONResult;
        }

        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            // you can use System.assert here and "if" calls to check the request and affect your return if you wish

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setBody(returned_SJSONResult);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** The uncovered code in shown in comments...
How can we cover this code?
Please tell me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please take some time and remove irrelevant code from your question so it is easier to read?

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: can you confirm thats there only 4 lines are not covered? cause as soon as you call **loadPage** method and **symbol** is not empty -- those lines should be covered

Comment: Yes, only these four lines are not covered. And The inner class just below the uncovered lines is neither showing as covered nor as uncovered. It shows no effect. Is this a problem?

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais I would suggest you to clear code coverage and rerun tests, because sometimes code coverage is showing weird, especially when you run tests from Developers Console

Comment: @Kurunve- No its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer for the question and is working for me.
Here we have to make some minor changes in code, where we are creating **GetAPIKeyMock** object and calling its constructor, here we have to pass the **string containing response result of httpRequest in json format**. We can get the response result from our org. by using System.debug logs, then store it in string variable and then **pass that variable in GetAPIKeyMoc**, Then it will cover the uncovered lines of code. In simple words, **It will cover json.deserialized object** as required.

Answer (score 1):

Im on mobile so apologies for brevity, but you can consider a few approaches. Either write a mock webservice (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html)

or

take this (http://blog.wdcigroup.net/2012/08/salesforce-web-service-callout-test-class/) approach, which is to return a hardcoded result to simulate the webservice callout. Hope this points you to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your HttpMock returns null

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new GetAPIKeyMock(class_test.result_of_httpReq));
```

The value of `class_test.result_of_httpReq` is null when the mock class's constructor is called.

Instead, you should do something like this

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new GetAPIKeyMock(someJsonString));
```

then, when the testmethod does:

```
class_test.loadPage();
```

which in turn makes an HTTP request, SFDC will invoke the mock class's `respond()` method that in turn returns the value of `someJsonString` to your PROD code.

You can build up a library of different`someJsonString` in static resources if they are complex and cycle through in different testmethods

Comment: Yes, I have got the answer.
You are same to my answer.